# Is it possible to define class methods within `class_eval`?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, class-eval

I know it's possible to define instance methods using `class_eval`. Is it possible to define class methods within the context of `class_eval`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible:

```
class Foo
end

Foo.class_eval do
  def self.bar
    puts "I'm a class method defined using class_eval and self"
  end

  def baz
    puts "I'm an instance method defined using class_eval without self"
  end
end

Foo.bar # => "I'm a class method defined using class_eval and self"

foo = Foo.new
foo.baz # => "I'm an instance method defined using class_eval without self"
```

As far as I can tell, this is because within `class_eval`, `self` is the Foo class, and doing `def Foo.bar` would create a class method.

Comment: Can you define using define_method

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo.class_eval do
  ...
end
```

is identical to:

```
class Foo
  ...
end
```

We need [Module#class_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) to operate on a variable that holds the name of a class. For example, if:

```
klass = Foo
```

you can write:

```
klass.class_eval do
  ...
end
```

whereas the keyword `class` demands a constant.

Here `class_eval` does two things:

- it changes `self` to the value of `klass` (`Foo`); and then it
- "opens" the value of `klass` (`Foo`) in the same way the keyword `class` does.